# PHP get text or value from dropdown list

Tags: php

I need a help again.

I need to solve the next problem.

I have to fill one dropdown list from database. If the user select one value, and press the submit button, I  have to send the user to the next page, and I should show for all details from this selected value.

Like if the selected value is Monitor, on the next page I have to show the price,and product name and etc in one table.

But I can't figure out how can I get the selected value from this dropdown list and what I should do.
This is my code, what is generate my dropdown list and working well.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("efszf_a") or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT nev FROM tanulok";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
?>

<select name="tanulok">
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option value=".$row['nev'].">".$row['nev']."</option>";
}
?>        
</select>
```

Please help me.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your select inside of a form, and have the form submission point to your next page. Like:

```
<form action='[yourNextPage.php]' method='post'>
    <select name="tanulok">
    <?php 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value=".$row['nev'].">".$row['nev']."</option>";
    }
    ?>        
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Then in your next page, you can access the value the user selected through the $_POST array, like:

```
$_POST['tanulok']
```

Comment: Thank for your promt help. That's what I need exactly. You are the best.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if your using post in php you will be able to get the value of the select option by using the select name like this

```
 $theSelectValue = $_POST['tanulok'];
```